# Blender Doesn't Permit Indices in Drivers?

Tags: python, scripting, drivers

I have a variable in a driver that I would like to be able to "switch on and off". To do this, I figured I could give this variable a power, another variable that would link to a custom property. I can then make the custom property 1, for enabled, or 0 for disabled - as a number to the power 0 is 1 and 1 multiplied by another number is just that other number.

I.e. x^y*z .

However Blender doesn't seem to support this. Here is the error from the console:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'float'

Any ideas as to why this is? It seems like pretty standard math to me. If not, any ideas how to get around it?

Comment: simple python syntax error, use `**` for power of.

Comment: not strictly a Blender issue either...  this would be equally well at home on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34258537/python-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-float-and-int

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it pertains to the meaning and effect of default operator symbols in Python.

Comment: Or just use `x * z  if y else x` as your driver expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub><sup>As I said in the [comments](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56001/blender-doesnt-permit-indices-in-drivers#comment95508_56001)</sup></sub>

Raising a value to a power is pretty standard math, something python can defiantly do.

Your trouble comes from a simple python syntax error. You are using `^` when the syntax in python is  `**` for power of (`^` is the bitwise XOR operator
).  As you can see here in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator) `**` is the the correct form.

You could alternatively use [pow()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#pow) function.